# Android sort ListView

Tags: android

I have an ListActivity which use data from DB..

```
setListAdapter(new CursorAdapter(myCursor));
```

This view have a column with a numbers. What i need is to sort them in descending whey when i click on a button. Its not a problem to write a new select with a new sort type..But how to refresh ListActivity ? Should I reuse setListAdapter ?

Comment: setting new sorted adapter via setListAdapter will refresh your view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a `CursorAdapter` it would be best to have the db sort the list. So just create a new Cursor and call `setListAdapter` again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can reuse the `setListAdapter()` method, after recreating a new `CursorAdapter` with the new reordered `Cursor`.

Comment: Sure he can, but should he? Mb there's more efficient way to reorder that list?

Comment: As the cursor is rebuilt, it's the simpliest way.